# How can I show code from a textarea with inline styling?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My app consists of 2 components.

On the left I have a text area that saves the input into a state variable, passes down to another component that will "translate" the input and display else.
Since the input will be translated to html code, I'd like to display the styled code on the right (it's an email form and pretty much the `andlt;` will be changed into < and the `andgt;` will be >).

So the end result will be html code with inline styling. How could I output the result styled and all?

The idea kinda looks like codepen in my head. Thanks!

So far I have these components done:

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";

// component imports
import TextFields from "../TextFields/TextFields";
import Display from "../EmailPart/Display";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Translate your shit here</h1>
      <div>
        <TextFields />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The text field part:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Display from "../EmailPart/Display";
import "./TextFields.css";

    const TextFields = () => {
      const [input, setInput] = useState([""]);
    
      return (
        <div class='text_holder'>
          <textarea
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            className='input_field'>
            Put your amazing shit herer
          </textarea>
          <div class='display_holder'>
            <Display input={input} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default TextFields;
```

And the display:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Display = (props) => {
  const { input } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{input}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Display;
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Are you saying the <Display> component would be showing inline HTML and CSS?  where did the CSS come from?   Could you give an example of the expected output? how much boilerplate?


```markdown
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p style="color: brown;">Put your amazing shit herer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes sure I'm sorry if i wasnt too clear.
So my goal is pretty much what you can see on codepen.io, you put the html code into a "text field" on the left and you see the "webpage" on the right

Comment: Much more boilerplate, lets say 5-6 times more than you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop. It's NOT recommended because your site will be vulnerable to XSS-Attacks.

here's a simple code:

```
function createMarkup(input) {
  return { __html: input } //the key has to be "__html" exactly
}

function Display({ input }) {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(input)} />
  )
}
```